# list of supported LDAP providers with Spring LDAP

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-ldap

We are using Spring LDAP 1.3.1 (Spring Security 3.2.5) and wonder if there is a list of supported LDAP servers. I haven't found such a list so I assume it should work with any LDAP, is that correct or there are limitation?

We would like to support next providers:

1. Sun Directory Server
2. Lotus Domino Directory
3. IBM Directory Server
4. Novell eDirectory
5. Oracle Internet Directory
6. Microsoft Active Directory Application Server

Answer (score 1):

Since LDAP is a Vendor-neutral,Internet Standard protocol and Spring LDAP follows the LDAP spec, any Directory Server that claims to support LDAP should be accessible with Spring LDAP in theory.Same as we are able to access a Web Server same way using HTTP regardless of the Web Server Provider.If there is no definite list of supported servers available. You could look into the LDAP specs of each provider for  the **LDAP version supported** (latest is [LDAP v3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511)) and the limitations(if any).